# what kind of locks are applied by Azure Synapse when loading data using COPY INTO

Tags: azure-synapse

what kind of locks are applied by Azure Synapse when loading data using COPY INTO, if we are running extract from synapse dw (say from table A) and simultaneously loading new data into a some other (say table B). Will it cause any locks, will we face slowness or any locks while extracting data from table A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a shared update lock on the table during write, and your select is blocked for the duration of the COPY INTO.